# Kingfisher can't setImage for UIButton

Tags: swift, image, uibutton, kingfisher

code is:

```
let url = URL(string: (user?.avatar)!)!
    print(url.absoluteString)
    let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url, cacheKey: "my_avatar")
    testUIButton.kf.setImage(with: resource, for:.normal)
```

The result is testUIButton display TintColor,No Image will be displayed.

Comment: url is valid string.

Comment: Final result is we must set a placeholder image for ImageButton.It seems to be same as in Android Envrionment.

Comment: `imageButton.kf.setBackgroundImage(with: url, for: .normal)`
try this.

Answer (score 4):

Try To Set `UIButton` Type `Custom`. This works for me.

```
let btnCustom = UIButton(type: .custom)
        
 if let imgURL = URL(string: imgURLString) {
       btnCustom.kf.setImage(with: imgURL, for: .normal)
 } else {
     btnCustom.setImage(UIImage(named: "img_user"), for: .normal)
 }
    
 btnCustom.cornerRadius = 15
 btnCustom.clipsToBounds = true
 btnCustom.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.customAction)), for: .touchUpInside)
 view.addSubview(btnCustom)
```

Answer (score 2):

Final result is we must set a placeholder image for ImageButton.It seems to be same as in Android dev envrionment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use modifier as below:

```
let modifier = AnyImageModifier { return $0.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) }
button.kf.setImage(with: url, for: .normal, placeholder: nil, options: [.imageModifier(modifier)], progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
```